# getting the path of a MailMessage attachment

Tags: c#, save, mailmessage

I'm using a MailMessage Queue and upon exiting the program I want to save the content of the queue.

I created a temp list and pass the contents of the queue to that. After that use a simple
`StreamWriter` to write each info out.

The only thing I can't seem to get is the path of the attachment. As far as I know I can't just simply save out the mailmessages so I thought this will work just as well, but if there is simpler/different solution that's great.

```
List<MailMessage> temp = queue.ToList<MailMessage>();
Stream stream = File.Open("Queue" +".osl", FileMode.Create);
StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(stream);
foreach (MailMessage x in temp)
{
    s.WriteLine(x.From.Address + x.To[0].Address + x.Body + x.Subject + x.Attachments[0].Name);
}
s.Close();
stream.Close();
```

Comment: the Name of the attachment is just simply the name of the file, I don't know the full path from that so I can't add the attachment again if I reopen the program.

Comment: I figured it out! Using

    FileInfo asd = new FileInfo(x.Attachments[0].Name);

I get the full info back and then I can just write this out and use it again to reattach the files.

Comment: @SaintHUN - If you've solved it, you can post your method as an answer and then accept it in a couple of days.

Comment: I'm still a new member so I need 7 hours to be able to Answer the question :P

Comment: Damn it nevermind, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @SaintHUN - Is the FileInfo bringing back an incomplete result?

Comment: Which path are you referring to? The original path from when the attachment was added? That won't be available.

Comment: Yes I want the original file path. So it seems I can't do anything else besides adding a new list that holds me the complete path for me. I didn't want to do that.
@keyboardP the FileInfo brings back a full path just not the right one. It assumes that the files are where the program is and this is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but there is no answer here, and this really works:

```
(attachmentObject.ContentStream as System.IO.FileStream).Name
```

In your specific case it would be:

```
s.WriteLine(x.From.Address + x.To[0].Address + x.Body + x.Subject + (x.Attachments[0].ContentStream as System.IO.FileStream).Name);
```

Hope it helps somebody!

Comment: And last but not least : you get ContentStream from Microsoft.SharePoint.Client reference. Tested, It works for me too.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use:

```
Path.GetFullPath(x.Attachments[0].Name);
```

Comment: Yes this retrieves a full path but not the one the actual file. This method will just assume that the file is where the program is. It seems like the easiest and so far only working way is to use a List while I'm adding an attachment and save the info to there.

Comment: -1 This concatenates the assembly path with the attachment name, which has nothing to do with the question...